# Developing a console based banking application in C#!

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c#-3.0

I am developing a console based banking application in C#! i have to get details of account dynamically..I am confused what to use whether array of objects or List. As i am beginner i dont know much about both . Could anyone help me what to use? i should save account details of savings and overdraft account separately . I should retrieve data based on account number to perform withdraw and deposit also. So kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you know the different, [use a `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) for everything. `List`s implement what is called a dynamic array behind the scenes, which is a regular array who's size is increased on demand.

Example usage:

```
// Create an integer array
List<int> list = new List<int>();

// Add 5 numbers
list.Add(1);
list.Add(5);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(2);

// Get value at index 0 and write to console
Console.WriteLine(list[0]); // 1
```

Here is some more advanced usage using LINQ which was introduced in .NET 3.5.

```
// Get all values less than 4 and put into an 'IEnumerable'
var lessThanFour = list.Where(e => e < 4);

// Write all values less than 4 to the console
foreach (var val in lessThanFour)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

Comment: any example on how to store it and retrieve from list ?

Comment: This should be your accepted answer. I will caution you though that interfacing with a bank can be a serious matter. Not understanding the difference between and Array and a List<T> is a cause for concern.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I'm going to help you design your data structures, but I doubt anyone is going to directly give you the code.

---

**Account Class**

It sounds like, to me, you want a class Account. An `Account` might have certain values:

- An account holder.
- An account number.
- A balance.

This should give you some idea of the fields inside the `Account` class.

In terms of the class' functionality, it looks like you want to be able to:

- GET the account Number.
- GET the account balance
- GET the account holder.
- SET the new account balance

You also mentioned you want different types of accounts. Read up a little on [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and that should spark your creativity.

---

**Storage Mechanism**

If it were me, I would store it in a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). A list is a dynamic object, meaning you can have as many account objects stored in it as you want. To use a list, you should read the documentation provided.

---

Hopefully this will help you solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not really saying exactly what you need to do with your collection, but overall, a `List<someObject>` will be more flexable, but will cause more performance hits.

If you're using `someObject[]`, it could potentially be more performant, but at the expense of "features".

Basically, rock a `List<someObject>` and have fun.